# Browse fragment customisation

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I want to customize a **`BrowseFragment`**.

Normally, a `BrowseFragment` is composed of multiple rows (header + items).

**My question** : Is it possible to have, for a same row (highlighted in blue), differents item types ? (see image below).

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You mean you want data in with two different categories in single `list row ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using [Presenter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/Presenter.html) to implement customization of the header views in a more complex layout. And as mentioned in [Creating a Catalog Browser](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/browse.html), also with the use of adapters and presenters, the `BrowseFragment` class allows you to define and display browsable media content categories and media items from a media catalog.

For better understanding and more samples, you may want to also check these tutorials:

- [BrowseFragment ListRow customization](http://corochann.com/browsefragment-listrow-customization-android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-18-705.html)
- [Construction of BrowseFragment](http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-2-85.html)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PresenterSelector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PresenterSelector.html)

Here is an example provided by Google: [CardPresenterSelector.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/support/v17/leanback/supportleanbackshowcase/cards/presenters/CardPresenterSelector.java). The example is part of [Leanback-Showcase](https://github.com/googlesamples/leanback-showcase), if you download and run it you'll notice they don't actually do what you are specifically looking for - but I believe its setup to do so if you just made some edits in the CardPresenterSelector (linked above). (There's also a nice [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QFHIfQy8_Wc) to go along with it)